# php codeigniter foreach static data rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make static data row in table for 10 rows. I have 3 data foreach (item01, item02, item03) like this.

```
<table>
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->item_no; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;
</table>
```

I want to make in my table like this :

| No | Item No |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item01 |
| 2 | Item02 |
| 3 | Item03 |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 |  |
| 10 |  |

How I can do that in my php code ?

Comment: can you please explain what you want to achieve? Is it just to print ten rows from `item01` to `item10`? what do you mean with: *I have 3 data foreach (item01, item02, item03) like this.*?

Comment: Yes, I want to print ten rows only in my 3 rows data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forloop to loop 10 row for the table.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    <tr>
        <td><?= $i + 1 ?></td>
        <td><?= ($data[$i]) ? $data[$i]->item_no : '' ?></td>
    </tr>
}
```

This code meaning if $data is not empty then show $data->item_no else show empty.

```
<?= ($data[$i]) ? $data[$i]->item_no : '' ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Chee Chong Tay. I appreciated, can you tell me the meaning of $data[$i] ?? I still learn programming.

Comment: Hi, jije

for example

$data = [];
The result will show "Empty";

$data = [0];
The result will show "Exist";

//IF THE DATA COUNT IS > 0
if($data){
    echo 'Exist';
} else {
    //IF THE DATA COUNT IS == 0
    echo 'Empty';
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<table>
<?php while(@$count<10){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=@$count+=1;?></td>
    <td>item<?=sprintf("%02d", @$count);?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$items = ['items 01', 'items 02', 'items 03', 'items 04'];
$output = '';
if( !empty($items) ){
  $i = 1;
  $output .= '<table>';
  foreach( $items as $item ){
          $output .= '<tr>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$item.'</td>';
          $output .= '</tr>';
          
          $i++;
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Don't forget the wrap the PHP snippet with
<?php
// ...
?>

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question

Answer (score -1):

first get the size of your data:

```
$items=count($data);
```

then you could simply use a for loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){  
    if($i<$items){
        $line=$data[$i]->item_no;
    }else{
        $line="nothing here in line:" . $i+1;
    }
    echo "<br>$line";
}
```

which outputs:

> ```
> item01
> item02
> item03
> nothing here in line:4
> nothing here in line:5
> nothing here in line:6
> nothing here in line:7
> nothing here in line:8
> nothing here in line:9
> nothing here in line:10
> ```

Comment: The OP asked about a table, not a load of text with line breaks

Comment: @SteveWright the question is about how to fill the "empty" rows, which my answer does. I don't think I have to tell them how to wrap a table around my solution, as it is basic html? Or should I?